# Phonegap : iOS and Android app update notification

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Now i develop an app for IOS and Android in Phonegap 3.5

How does the iOS or Android app update mechanism work? How to tell user that application on Appstore or PlayStore has been updated?Do i have to write the functionality in the code to show the update popover or is it handled by Appstore or PlayStore to show notification to user that app has been updated. What's the way to make  update notification with phonegap ?

Answer (score 0):

If you using IBM worklight, it's not possible. Worklight will automatically inform users the latest app and at the same time it can lock all old version app.

Besides that, you can send push notification to inform users to install latest app from google play/itune store.

Reference: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html